# How to display only one validation error message with a <tr:panelLabelAndMessage> with MyFaces Trinidad?

Tags: webforms, myfaces, trinidad

For a registration form I have something simple like:

```
        <tr:panelLabelAndMessage
            label="Zip/City"
            showRequired="true">
            <tr:inputText 
                id="zip"
                value="#{data['registration'].zipCode}" 
                contentStyle="width:36px"
                simple="true"
                required="true" />
            <tr:inputText 
                id="city"
                value="#{data['registration'].city}" 
                contentStyle="width:133px"
                simple="true"
                required="true" />
        </tr:panelLabelAndMessage>
        <tr:message for="zip" />
        <tr:message for="city" />
```

When including the last two lines, I get two messages on validation error. When ommiting last to lines, a javascript alert shows up, which is not what I want.

Is there a solution to show only one validation failed message somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, the fields must layout horizontally. It's a no-go to put ZIP field and city not next to each other in one line. At least for me.

A co-worker has pointed me to set a faclets variable inside the first tr:message and to put a rendered attribute at the second one that reacts on this variable. Havn't got the time to try nor found the right command for setting a varable yet. Will post results as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't be ideal, but if you remove the `panelLabelAndMessage` tag and just use the label attribute on the `inputText` tag that should remove the extra error message.